# Replace en sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Tengo una query en SQL que funciona bien, y estoy intentando incluirla en mi API que tiene SQLAlchemy.
Esta es la query que se ejecuta bien:

```
 SELECT * FROM Cliente WHERE (REPLACE (numeroDocumento,'-','')) like '30699583533'
```

En mis registros en la BD tengo algunos campos sin guiones y otros con guiones, es por eso que necesitaría una búsqueda que pueda buscar omitiendo los guiones.

La query que realizo sin problema desde mi API pero que solo me sirve para aquellos números que no tienen guiones es:

```
@app.route('/getclientid/<dni>', methods=['GET'])
@requires_auth
def getclientid_get(dni):
if request.method == 'GET':
    checkclient = cliente.query.filter_by(numerodocumento = dni).all()
    return jsonify({'cliente': [elemento.as_dict() for elemento in checkclient] })
```

Alguna sugerencia al respecto, desde ya muchísimas gracias y perdón por aun mi faltas de conocimientos de python y sqlalchemy.

Comment: publica el contenido de tu cadena `numeroDocumento`

Comment: El contenido que puede tener `numeroDocumento` en la tabla es:

11657582 o 30-22974156-7

son numeros de ese tipo, cualquiera de las dos formas.

Comment: en el ejemplo que puse despues de `like` seria que quiero buscarlo ingresando 30699583533, pero en la BD esta guardado como 30-69958353-3

Comment: debes usar expresiones regulares, prueba modificando tu cadena `"30-69958353-3"` a `"/30-?69958353-?3/"` el parametro `"?"` significa que sea opcional que aparesca el guion

Comment: en donde quieres que modifique eso? la BD no puedo tocarla, y la API recibe una cadena de numero sin simbolos..